# Apollo and GraphQL CORS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, cors, graphql, react-apollo

Running into a frustrating issue with Apollo getting content from a Rails backend. The issue seems to be resolving around the use of CORS in my Apollo project.

**Tech**

- apollo-client: 1.9.3
- graphql: 0.11.7
- react: 15.6.1
- react-apollo: 1.4.16

**cors.rb**

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins `*`

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

*rails is running on port 3001* `rails s -p 3001`

With this backend you can make `curl` requests and everything works as expected

**Working Curl**

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"query": "{users{first_name}}"}' http://localhost:3001/graphql
```

This returns back expected data

---

So this is all pointing to an issue with Apollo and the frontend of the application.

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import ApolloClient from 'apollo-client';
import { ApolloProvider, createNetworkInterface } from 'react-apollo';

import App from './containers/App.jsx';

const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql', <<<<< There is a different endpoint then the standard 'graphql' which is why this is declared
  })
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import gql from 'graphql-tag';
import { graphql } from 'react-apollo';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    console.log(this.props);
    return (
      <div>Application</div>
    );
  }
}

const query = gql`
  {
    users {
      first_name
    }
  }
`;

export default graphql(query)(App);
```

This returns the error

> Failed to load http://localhost:3001/graphql: Response to preflight
>   request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
>   mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

**app.jsx (change mode)**

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  networkInterface: createNetworkInterface({
    uri: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql',
    opts: {
      mode: 'no-cors'
    }
  })
});
```

This returns the error

> Unhandled (in react-apollo) Error: Network error: Network request
>   failed with status 0 - ""`

Looking at the request:

GENERAL

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3001/graphql
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:[::1]:3001
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

RESPONSE HEADERS

Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin

REQUEST HEADERS

```
Accept:*/*
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:87
Content-Type:text/plain;charset=UTF-8 <<< I'm wondering if this needs to be application/json?
Host:localhost:3001
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Referer:http://localhost:8080/
User-Agent:Chrome/61
```

REQUEST PAYLOAD

```
{query: "{↵ users {↵ first_name↵ __typename↵ }↵}↵", operationName: null}
operationName
:
null
query
:
"{↵  users {↵    first_name↵    __typename↵  }↵}↵"
```

---

So what I did to get some sort of response was to install the Chrome Extension [Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

If `mode: 'no-cors'` is removed and this extension is active, data can be retrieved.

---

In looking through the Apollo docs I'm unable to find much on this topic. I tried implementing the [Apollo Auth Header](http://dev.apollodata.com/react/auth.html#Header) but this simply produced the same errors as above.

What in my Apollo code could be causing these errors? And what steps are there to fix the problem?

Searching over GitHub issues and other Google searches are either for much-older versions of Apollo in which issues "have been addressed" or do not work when implemented.

**Edit**

Adding Ruby on Rails tag just in case there is more configuration needed in Rails. Upon researching the Apollo Client issues found [Network error: Network request failed with status 0 - ""](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/2004) This issued was resolved by the OP because of an issue on the backend.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue was in the **cors.rb** file

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins `*`

    resource '*',
    headers: :any,
    methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

The issue was `origins '*'` had backticks instead of quotes

Was also able to remove the `opts` object in the **index.jsx** and everything is working as expected